# How to access one single collection in a database in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When connecting to MongoDB with a Node.JS application using express, how do you connect to just one collection if the database has multiple collections?

I have the following MONGODB_URI:

MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://username:******@cluster0.dayw5.mongodb.net/phonebook?retryWrites=true&w=majority

The database "phonebook" has three collections, "numbers", "users" and "people". How do you change the MONGODB_URI to just connect to "numbers" ?

At the moment, the connection is successful, but nothing is being fetched.

Comment: Show some code, but bascily: `client.collection("foo")`. You cant just "connect" to one collection. You connect to the database server (and select one or more databases/collections).

Answer (score 0):

You don't; the connection URI is granular to the database only, in your case `phonebook`.  From the resources returned, you must specify a collection to access e.g. `coll = db['users']` and then perform operations against that collection object e.g.

```js
c = coll.find({name:"foo"});
c.forEach(function(doc) {
    printjson(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers given above are basically correct.

I tried to connect to an existing collection but was unable to do so. Instead, MongoDB automatically creates a new collection in the database and gives it a new, custom name: "people" in my case which I did not specify anywhere.